# Combine two records into one and update column

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following records in my CartItems table:

[image]

When I migrate the cart, I'd like to combine the two records into one with the cart id of Test1 and then update the quantity to 2.

So it would be  CartItemId 84, CartId Test1, Quantity 2, DateCreated 5/21/2013, ProductId 16

How would I do this in linq/EF?

EDIT

```
 public void MigrateCart(string userName)
    {
        ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();

        var shoppingCart = _context.ShoppingCartItems.Where(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId);

        foreach (var item in shoppingCart)
        {
            item.CartId = userName;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

EDIT

I think I have it.

```
public void MigrateCart(string userName)
    {
        ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();

        if (ShoppingCartId != userName)
        {
            var shoppingCart = _context.ShoppingCartItems.Where(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId).ToList();
            var userShoppingCartItems = _context.ShoppingCartItems.Where(c => c.CartId == userName).ToList();

            foreach (var item in shoppingCart)
            {
                foreach (var userShoppingCartItem in userShoppingCartItems)
                {
                    if (item.ProductId == userShoppingCartItem.ProductId)
                    {
                        item.Quantity += userShoppingCartItem.Quantity;
                        item.CartId = userName;
                        _context.ShoppingCartItems.Remove(userShoppingCartItem);
                    }
                }
                item.CartId = userName;
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
        else
        {
            var shoppingCart = _context.ShoppingCartItems.Where(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId);

            foreach (var item in shoppingCart)
            {
                item.CartId = userName;
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you don't ask how to get the two items, I just give you a really rustic way.

```
var item1 = context.CartItems.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 84);
var item2 = context.CartItems.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 85);

item1.Quantity += item2.Quantity;//add quantity of item2 to item1
context.CartItems.Remove(item2);//remove item2
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include the MigrateCart code. My thought would be to pull in a list of cart items that have already been assigned to the user name I'm passing in. So I'd have two lists one based off the shopping cart id and one based off the username.

Comment: @Mike sorry but it's not clear for me... You want to merge all the cartItems with a cartId of "Test1" (username) with the ones with a cartId of "19af129b..." ? What does `GetCartId` do ? And you want to remove cartItem 85, right ?